# How to get right lat and long with watchPosition (js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation, gps

I'm using `watchPosition` method in order to retrieve latitude and longitude live (when the user move, they change). The problem is that I'm getting wrong latitude and longitude: wrong third decimal digit.

Implementation code here:

```
export class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pos:null
    };
  }
   componentDidMount(){
    if (navigator.geolocation){
      navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
        (position)=>{
          console.log("lat: ", position.coords.latitude);
          console.log("long: ", position.coords.longitude);
          this.setState({pos:position});
        },
          (err) => console.warn(err.code),
          {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
        )
    }else{
      console.log("Allow position pls");
    }
  }
  render (){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ApiCall props={this.state}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
export default App;
```

For istance: I get latitude 45.7526304, when right latitude should be 45.7548103

Any ideas on why that occurs?

Comment: just out of curiosity, 7 digits should give you around 30cm of accuracy, do you really need more than that? From my experience, even if there are more digits, on common hardware they are not reliable.

Comment: Seeing the edited version of your answer. The precision of gps devices is affected by multiple factors like weather conditions, buildings, etc. To get better precision you need to know the hardware and it's limits, 10m is pretty good precision on most gps devices. You can go to the [gis stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com) to get a better insight on this as it is really technical.

Comment: Just another note, you should look at the `accuracy` that I think is returned in the `position.coords` parameter. If it is filled, it can give you a hint on the accuracy of the position